# Rock, Paper, Scissors -- Python

Tags: python

When ever I run my code, it will give the correct answer, but, the answer keeps repeating until I kill the program. I would I fix this issue.

```
import random

RPS = ("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors")
computer = random.choice(RPS)
Player = input("Enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors : ")
player = False

while player == False:
    if Player == computer:
        print("It is a tie")
    elif Player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("You have lost,", computer, "covers", Player)
        else:
            print("You win,", player, "beats", computer)
    elif Player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("You have lost,", computer, "breaks", Player)
        else:
            print("You win,", Player, "beats", computer)
    elif Player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("You have lost,", computer, "cuts", Player)
        else:
            print("You win,", Player, "beats", computer)
    else:
        print("That is a invalid entry")
```

Comment: Do you understand why it keeps repeating?

Answer (score 2):

You are looping `while player == False`. This is something you set before the loop starts, and do not modify at any point during the loop. As a result, player will always equal `False`. You can either set `player = True` during the loop, or utilize `break`.

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/break-continue

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems in your code:

- You have infinite loop since `player` is initialized to `False` before the loop and is not changed inside of it (but maybe this is the desired behaviour - game with infinite rounds till the program is killed).
- The main problem that both the computer and the user choice are outside the loop and it causes them to be picked once and stay the same during all you game. If you want to change the picked values in each round, move those line inside the loop.

To change the game to be with predefined number of rounds, try this:

```
import random
rounds = 3 # you can change it
for _ in range(rounds):
    RPS = ("Rock", "Paper", "Scissors")
    computer = random.choice(RPS)
    Player = input("Enter Rock, Paper, or Scissors : ")
    if Player == computer:
        print("It is a tie")
    elif Player == "Rock":
        if computer == "Paper":
            print("You have lost,", computer, "covers", Player)
        else:
            print("You win,", Player, "beats", computer)
    elif Player == "Scissors":
        if computer == "Rock":
            print("You have lost,", computer, "breaks", Player)
        else:
            print("You win,", Player, "beats", computer)
    elif Player == "Paper":
        if computer == "Scissors":
            print("You have lost,", computer, "cuts", Player)
        else:
            print("You win,", Player, "beats", computer)
    else:
        print("That is a invalid entry")
```